# Fetch the data from GITHUB API

Tags: javascript, angular

I want to get all the data from github API. But it doesn't work for me.
My .ts file is below:

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { GitTakeService } from "app/git-take.service";

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent {
  user:any;

constructor(private gittakeService:GitTakeService ){

  this.gittakeService.getUser().subscribe(user=>{
    debugger;
    this.user=user;
    console.log(user);
  })

}
}
```

My service is below:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import {Http,Response, Headers} from '@angular/http'
import'rxjs/add/operator/map';

@Injectable()
export class GitTakeService {

  constructor(private http:Http) { }


  getUser(){
    debugger;
    return this.http.get("http://api.github.com/users")
        .map(
          (resp:Response)=>{

           return resp.json().response;
          }
        );    
  }    
}
```

When consoling the user in .ts file, it shows undefined. My view file is like this:

## {{user}}

Anyone please help me to solve this problem?

Comment: can you please `console.log(resp);`?

Comment: The response is consoling.the response is the github data.but it is not subscribing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are receiving is an array, so you want to use `resp.json()` instead of `resp.json().response` there is no such property like `response` in your response. So your map should look like this:

```
getUser(){
  debugger;
  return this.http.get("http://api.github.com/users")
    .map((resp:Response)=>{
       return resp.json();
    });    
}
```

and in your component I would name the array `users` instead of `user`, since there are several users in your response. Also I suggest you keep anything unnecessary from the constructor and use `OnInit` instead:

```
users = [];

constructor(private gittakeService:GitTakeService ){ }

ngOnInit() {
  this.gittakeService.getUser()
    .subscribe(data => {
       this.users = data;
    });
}
```

Then you can iterate the array and use **the property names** to show the properties of one `user` object:

```
<div *ngFor="let user of users">
  {{user.login}}
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

`resp.json().response` is undefined `resp.json()` is what you want

the service function:

```
getUser(){
   return this.http.get("http://api.github.com/users")
    .map(
      (resp:Response)=>{

       return resp.json();
      }
    );
```

}`

and the component:

```
this.gittakeService.getUser().subscribe(users=>{
    this.user=users[0];
    console.log(user);
})
```

Comment: sir its consoling fine.sir how to show all data into view

Comment: is `resp.json().response` consoling fine?

Comment: [object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object]

Comment: like this,what is the solution

Comment: <h1>{{user}}</h1> this is my view

Comment: can you provide a plunker?